# Basic encryption/RSA prime number concept? [beginner]

Tags: encryption, rsa, composite

so I understand that for RSA encryption, you multiply two large primes to get a very large composite number, which is your public key. The two large primes are your private key, so you want to keep both of those primes secret, and you can do so because it is impossible for the computer to guess them, because you would have to increment your guess by 1 each time for a long time, because each prime number is so large.

However my question is: why won't composite numbers work as well for this? If one of the large primes in your private key was a large composite, wouldn't you still have to guess it by incrementing by 2,3,5,7,11, etc? I know incrementing like this wouldn't take as long as incrementing by 1, but it would still take a long time because you don't know whether to increment by 2,3,5,7, etc.

Although if incrementing by 2 doesn't work, you can be sure private key < publickey/2, if incrementing by 3 doesnt work you can be sure that private key < publickey/3, and so on.

But anyways, can someone tell me why composite numbers aren't as good for encryption? How would you guess a large composite?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [security.se]

Comment: @MikeW What about [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of prime numbers isn't about the difficulty of factoring - the most efficient method for factoring large composite numbers like the modulus of an RSA key is the [General Number Field Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve), which is much more efficient than simply trying to divide by successive numbers.

In fact, your statement that it doesn't work with composite numbers isn't really true - whilst RSA is generally performed using two primes, it still works more than two distinct primes, and since every composite number is a product of primes, you could choose two composite numbers (providing they are the product of *distinct* primes, and have no common factors) and the algorithm will still work.

For example, if we choose two composite numbers with distinct prime factors and no common factors:

```
a = 15 (= 3 * 5)
b = 77 (= 7 * 11)
```

This is equivalent to 4-prime RSA:

```
p = 3
q = 5
r = 7
s = 11
```

So far, so good however you go on to say that the "primes are your private key", which isn't really true either - the private key is actually the combination of the modulus `n = p * q` (which is also part of the public key), and the *private exponent*, which is the number `d` such that `e * d = 1 mod phi(n)` where `e` is the public exponent (which is often just 65537), and `phi` is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Once `d` is calculated, the original primes can be discarded.

The problem is that calculating `phi(n)` requires knowing the prime factors of `n`. In ordinary RSA where `n = p * q` we already know the prime factors of `n`, but if we instead chose two composite numbers (like the `a` and `b` above) and use `n = a * b` we need to factor these numbers in order to calculate `phi(n)`. Since the security of RSA itself relies on the difficulty of factoring large composite numbers, it is infeasible to calculate the private exponent if we haven't constructed the modulus directly from its prime factors, which is the real reason that you have to use primes rather than composite numbers.

Answer (score -1):

because, like you said, with a prime number you have to increment by one. So if I have the number 13, it would take me 13 steps to get to the number 13 since it's prime so I'd be incrementing by one. But, if I have the number 14, it would only take me 7 steps to get there because i could go by twos. And the larger you scale the numbers the bigger the difference in them is. And I will admit you don't know what you need to increment by, but even incrementing by 2 is still faster than by one

Comment: " And I will admit you don't know what you need to increment by" -that is exactly my point.

Comment: @user3133300 but, assuming you don't know that they aren't prime I would increment by 2 because it is faster. Now in the case of RSA we all know that they're prime but we may not know that for all encryption styles.

Comment: yes but what if the composite number is odd, like 15? Then incrementing by 2 won't work and you would have to then increment by something else.

Comment: @user3133300 yes you would but then you know that all even numbers wouldn't work anymore, so then you could keep going by 3 and so on, now the more numbers you go by the more steps it will take so eventually it can get to be more inefficient than increment by one. For example in RSA where they pick a large number, it would be most likely be more efficient to go up by one than to try 2,3,etc... But you could also save steps in increment that way assuming you cache your results.

Comment: So you're saying that in some cases it is actually more efficient to increment by 1?

Comment: Yes is some certain special cases where the number is extremely large and is only divisible by high primes (example 2^31-1) it would be better to increment by one because you would have tons of steps, you can cut down on lots of steps by caching the numbers that don't work though

Comment: Factoring composite numbers by trial divisions is only viable for relatively small numbers (the kind you could do on paper or with a calculator) an RSA modulus would have to be factored using something like a General Number Field Sieve.